# oracle: pivot on dynamic dates

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have this query:

```
select pvt1.*
from 
(
   select
      TO_CHAR(DateAppointment, 'yyyy-mm-dd') as currentDay,
      count(*) myCounter
      [...]

   from (
      select 
         [...]
      from myTable

   ) a
   group by [...]
   order by DateAppointment
) source1
PIVOT
(
    max(myCounter)
    --FOR currentDay IN ('2012-08-20', '2012-08-21', '2012-08-27', '2012-09-03')
    FOR currentDay IN (
      SELECT  LISTAGG(datevalue, ', ')
      WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY datevalue) 
      FROM DATESLIST 
        ) 
)  pvt1;
```

This subquery just get the list of my dates from another table (DATESLIST), but when i run the first query, Oracle returns an error.

```
SELECT  LISTAGG(datevalue, ', ')
          WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY datevalue) 
          FROM DATESLIST
```

But when i use instead the following code, i get the correct results:

```
FOR currentDay IN ('2012-08-20', '2012-08-21', '2012-08-27', '2012-09-03')
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is because you can't use a query inside `in` clause in pivot

Comment: Actually it's not true. You can use a subquery inside IN but in this case you need to use XML keyword. Refer to the Oracle documentation

Comment: Thanks! Any example of subquery using xml to extract the list of dates?